# jquery how to detect current input id

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

i have a table that generated from yii2, i want to make a tabular input but before sending submit, there are a client validation to the input field. Consider i dont know the input id, because it is generated by yii2. Here's the code snippet of first row

```
<tr class="kv-tabform-row" data-key="4">
    <td class="kv-align-center kv-align-middle">1</td>
    <td class="kv-grid-hide kv-align-top">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-id">
            <input type="hidden" id="kegbulan-4-id" class="form-control" name="KegBulan[4][id]" value="4">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="kv-grid-hide kv-align-top">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-id_keg_ta_uk required">
            <input type="hidden" id="kegbulan-4-id_keg_ta_uk" class="form-control" name="KegBulan[4][id_keg_ta_uk]" value="6">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="kv-align-middle" style="width:300px;">Pengadaan Barang Kuasi, Buku Uji, Plat Uji dan Stiker Uji</td>
    <td class="kv-align-middle">
        <input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-anggaran" class="anggaran" name="KegBulan-[4][anggaran]" value="300,000,000" disabled="disabled" style="width:100px;"></td>
    <td class="kv-align-top">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-sp2d required">
            <input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-sp2d" class="form-control sp2d" name="KegBulan[4][sp2d]" value="680000" onchange="tesbos()">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="kv-align-top" style="width:70px;">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-persen_sp2d required">
            <input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-persen_sp2d" class="form-control" name="KegBulan[4][persen_sp2d]" value="2">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="kv-align-top">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-spj required">
            <input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-spj" class="form-control" name="KegBulan[4][spj]" value="680000">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="kv-align-top" style="width:70px;">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-persen_spj required">
            <input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-persen_spj" class="form-control" name="KegBulan[4][persen_spj]" value="2">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="kv-align-top" style="width:70px;">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-target required">
            <input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-target" class="form-control" name="KegBulan[4][target]" value="0">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="kv-align-top" style="width:70px;">
        <div class="form-group field-kegbulan-4-pfisik required">
            <input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-pfisik" class="form-control" name="KegBulan[4][pfisik]" value="10">
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="skip-export kv-align-center kv-align-middle" style="width:60px;"><a href="/yii2/yii-application/frontend/web/keg-bulan/view?id=4" title="View" data-pjax="0">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a> <a href="/yii2/yii-application/frontend/web/keg-bulan/update?id=4" title="Update" data-pjax="0" style="display:none;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a> <a href="/yii2/yii-application/frontend/web/keg-bulan/delete?id=4" title="Delete" data-confirm="Are you sure to delete this item?" data-method="post" data-pjax="0">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
    <td class="skip-export kv-align-center kv-align-middle kv-row-select" style="width:50px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection[]" value="4"></td>
</tr>
```

screenshoot : http://www.imagebam.com/image/569de2398154258

the input sp2d will check input anggaran and do some validation if (sp2d > anggaran) then "sp2d exceed anggaran limit"

Here the initial javascript function to check that function is triggered via onchange

```
function tesbos(){

   var sp2d = $(".sp2d").attr("id");
    console.log(sp2d);

}
```

when i go to row no 2 in sp2d input, still when i check my console log, it still print the sp2d input id of row #1, how to get my input id automatically/dynamically when i go to any row? any help would be appreciated

Comment: `<input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-sp2d" class="form-control sp2d" name="KegBulan[4][sp2d]" value="680000" onchange="tesbos(this)">` then `function tesbos(el){alert(el.id)}`

Comment: oh my goodness.... simply add (this) to onchange, i put (this) on the function, still, it return only object not the element id of input. thank you for your quick response. this is my first question on stackoverflow, never imagined got the answer so fast :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can change the markup, you need to pass the element refernce to the click handler

```
<input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-sp2d" class="form-control sp2d" name="KegBulan[4][sp2d]" value="680000" onchange="tesbos(this)">
```

then

```
function tesbos(el) {
    alert(el.id)
}
```

---

But I would recommend using jQuery event handlers instead of inlined one, so remove `onchange=""` from the markup

```
<input type="text" id="kegbulan-4-sp2d" class="form-control sp2d" name="KegBulan[4][sp2d]" value="680000">
```

then

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(".sp2d").change(function(){
        alert(this.id)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, each row of your table includes :

- an `anggaran` (budget) field [fixed value]
- a `sp2d` (spend to date) field [user entered].

And you want to perform a check, on change of every `sp2d` (spend to date) value against its corresponding `anggaran` (budget) value.

For this, you do not need to know either of the the fields' IDs. Simply find the `anggaran` field *relative to* whichever `sp2d` field triggers the change event.

First, delete `onchange="tesbos()"` from the HTML.

Then paste this code between `<script></script>` tags in your document's HEAD (or in a .js file if your code is organised that way).

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#containerID").on('change', ".sp2d", tesbos); // where containerID is the ID of eg. a DIV in which the YII table sits

    function tesbos() {
        var sp2d_value = $(this).val();
        var anggaran_value = $(this).closest("tr").find(".anggaran").val();//find the anggaran field in the same row, and grab its value.

        console.log(anggaran_value, sp2d_value);

        if(sp2d_value > anggaran_value) {
            //anggaran is exceeded
            ...
        } else {
            //anggaran is not exceeded
            ...
        }
    }
});
```